# Xposed - Can't hook static method

Tags: android, hook, xposed-framework

I try to hook `Settings.System.putInt` method which is `static`. One of the calls for this method is done in `setAirplaneModeOn` method of `com.android.settings.AirplaneModeEnabler` class. It is placed in `Settings` app of android. Also, `putInt` method is used in `com.android.systemui`.

However, following code doesn't hook `putInt` method. It doesn't give any exception, but it also doesn't dump any log message with content "`In android.provider.Settings.System`" which means `beforeHookedMethod` is not called or it couldn't be hooked. `Loaded app` logs are printed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
    if (!( lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.systemui") || lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.settings"))) {
        return;
    }
    XposedBridge.log("Loaded app: " + lpparam.packageName);
    final Class<?> mClass = XposedHelpers.findClass("android.provider.Settings$System", lpparam.classLoader);
    findAndHookMethod(mClass, "putInt", ContentResolver.class, String.class, "int",  new XC_MethodHook() {
        @Override
        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            XposedBridge.log("In android.provider.Settings.System");
        }
    });
}
```

Xposed-Framework version : 54

Android version: 4.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Jelly Bean MR1 (4.2) the method `setAirplaneModeOn` use `putInt` in `Settings.Global` instead `Settings.System` as you can see [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/jb-mr1-release/src/com/android/settings/AirplaneModeEnabler.java#L96).

Your code should be modified like this:

```
@Override
public void handleLoadPackage(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
    if (!(lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.systemui") || lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.settings"))) {
        return;
    }
    XposedBridge.log("Loaded app: " + lpparam.packageName);
    final Class<?> mClass = XposedHelpers.findClass("android.provider.Settings$Global", lpparam.classLoader);
    findAndHookMethod(mClass, "putInt", ContentResolver.class, String.class, int.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
        @Override
        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            XposedBridge.log("In android.provider.Settings.Global");
        }
    });
}
```

I tested the updated code with KitKat 4.4.4 and it works correctly.

Comment: Yes, using class `Global` instead of `Settings` has solved my problem. Thanks